# Slider create by Option tree plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello guys I am a new user here.

I have a problem ,
I want to create a slider by option tree plugin for wordpress theme and I created slider.But It don't show on my site. 
I am using this php code

please give me any suggestion .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have used `List Item` of Option Tree to create slider. See the sample code to retrieve slider

```
<?php               
$slider_data = ot_get_option( 'your_slider_id_here' );
foreach ($slider_data as $slider) { 
    //you will get sub-field of slider in array. 
    print_r($slider); 
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry not working ,Finally I found this code 

<?php if ( function_exists( 'ot_get_option' ) ) {
        /* get the slider array */
        $slides = ot_get_option( 'slider ID', array() );
        
        if ( ! empty( $slides ) ) {
       foreach( $slides as $slide ) {
         echo '
         <li>
        <a href="' . $slide['slide_link'] . '"></a>
        <img src="' . $slide['slide_image'] . '" alt="' . $slide['title'] . '" />
        <p class="vubon-caption">' . $slide['slide_caption'] . '</p>
        
         </li>';
       }
        }
        
      }?>

Comment: Both codes are same. Only you did it in complex way. Anyway have fun.

Comment: use $slider_data = ot_get_option( 'your_slider_id_here' );
print_r($slider_data); you will see same value